# URLDownloadToFile Function corrupting downloaded EXE

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to download an EXE using the `URLDownloadToFile` function. Yet, when it is downloaded, it corrupts the exe and gives the error message:

> This app can't run on your PC

The actual file size is 21kb, yet when it is downloaded using the function it turns into a 123KB file.

My code:

```
HRESULT hres = S_OK;
LPCTSTR vbURL = _T("https://linktofile.com/vb.exe"), vbPATH = _T("C:\\Desktop\\vb.exe");
hres = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, vbURL, vbPATH, 0, NULL);
system("start C:\\Desktop\\vb.exe");
```

Comment: Are you sure that you just didn't download and got infested with a nasty virus?

Comment: Another possibility is the link doesn't actually download the file directly, you only download an HTML file that when run by the browser properly gets the file.

Comment: @Martheen Thank you, that actually is what was happening. I noticed after i renamed the file to vb.html and opened it. Is there something I have to do so it downloads the exe itself or is URLDownloadToFile not capable of that?

Comment: URLDownloadToFile simply downloads data. It's not going to interpret the HTML file and follow browser redirect tags or execute javascript to download the real file - you need something like a browser to do that.

Comment: Well if it's for specific sites, you might be able to check the HTML or the JS it refers to and extract the direct URL from there, otherwise, you need something like Selenium

Comment: It would be better to forgo using `URLDownloadToFile()` at all, and just use WinInet instead (or other HTTP library). That way, you have more control over the download, and more importantly you have access to the HTTP headers to see what kind of data is actually being downloaded. Just because you request an EXE file doesn't guarantee you are going to get an EXE file. And `URLDownloadToFile()` won't tell you if that happens.